# How to properly call a multithreaded method inside a class in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I've got a method to download a bunch of files, and then do things with them.

The multithreaded download methods worked when not in a class, but when I put them inside the class, they cease processing immediately after initiating the first file in the list.  There are no errors thrown; the URL call is good, etc. So I am probably missing something related to OOP in python.

```
from multiprocessing import cpu_count
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
import os
from requests import Session
import time


class OSM

    def __init__(self):
        self.url_root = "https://my.site/index.html"
        self.s = self._mount_session()
        self.data = None  # zip object of download links and associated local paths
        self.download_path = "C:/Temp"
        
    def _download_parallel(self, args):
        results = ThreadPool(cpu_count() - 1).imap_unordered(self._download_url, args)
        for result in results:
            print(f"URL: {result[0]} | Time (s): {result[1]}")

    def _download_url(self, args):
        t0 = time.time()
        url, fn = args[0], args[1]
        try:
            r = self.s.get(url)
            with open(fn, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(r.content)
            return (url, time.time() - t0)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Exception in _download_url(): {e}")
            pass

    def _mount_session(self):
        return Session()  # placefiller, the session is negotiated in here

    def download(self):
        # expose this to the user
        if not os.path.exists(self.download_path): os.makedirs(self.download_path)
        return self._download_parallel(self.data)

    def do_stuff_with_files(self):
        # process files, etc
        return

    def get_file_list(self):
        dl_links = []
        local_files = []
        # check the website, get list of links, create list of local files, zip together
        self.data = zip(dl_links, local_files)
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    o = OSM()
    o.get_file_list()
    o.download()
```

Comment: Please show relevant code without syntax errors

Comment: Have you checked that after call to `get_file_list` the resulting `self.data` is what it should be?

Comment: Yep, `self.data` produces a list of tuples (url, local download path).  I am thinking I'll need to just split this off as a `subprocess` call and wait for it to finish.

Comment: Assuming `self.data` is an iterable of tuples where each tuple is `(url, filename)`, then I don't see anything that would explain your issue except if your download fails with an exception, then your `_download_url` method will not return what `_download_parallel` expects, i.e. a tuple, and then `_download_parallel` will raise an exception. `_download_url` should always return a tuple and I suggest that the new, first element could be a True/False value representing success or failure.